# So, what about automatically removing 'so' or 'hey' if first word in post?

Tags: feature-request, automatic-edits

This is question is 30% tongue in cheek and 70% serious.

I don't know why, but questions on SO that start with the word 'So' (as in "So, I'm writing this killer app.."), or 'hey' are really annoying.

Those words in this position are redundant and usually the question will make perfect sense without them. Could they be removed automatically when a question is submitted?

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433638/fixing-zend-route-to-work-with-zend-navigation), which is not necessarily a bad question, but it does illustrate my point.

[Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1624710) is a list of affected posts on Stack Overflow since the beginning of 2022.

Comment: Can't say I'm too excited about all these automatic filters, but this one seems harmless enough.

Comment: Most salutations are [already removed from posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/159624). I don't know how I feel about "So, …" though. Yet another filter that's now really breaking intentional language aspects. I mean, yes, it's not perfect written style, but we're no English course here.

Comment: I don't get too obsessed about this, but I do remove these `salutations` if I am editing the post for some other reason. I wouldn't edit a post just for this. Well, I haven't done so yet :)

Comment: I've noticed a high correlation between starting a question with "so" and the question being of poor quality.

Comment: "hey" seems to be covered by the [mentioned filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115565/so-what-about-automatically-removing-so-or-hey-if-first-word-in-post#comment301371_115565): ...`hey(?![a-z])`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

Imo, no form of automatism can ever really solve general individualism issues.

It's the same thing as with the automatic deletion of salutations and closings:

- some will be happy that some more noise has been automatically removed
- some will be annoyed by the discussions and rollback wars such thing will produce
- some will still be unhappy that the rest of the post still is not keeping it to the point
- some will think "What's the problem? Why don't they just read over it?"
- some will think "Why I'm not allowed to be polite as usual when posting?"
- [.. insert gazillions of more individual thoughts here ...]

Answer (score 4):

Why not also remove these "no value", but all too common, closings:

- Any help appreciated
- Thanks
- Any ideas?

I'm all for being polite, but keep it to the point. Salutations and niceties are not needed and just take up screen real estate.

Answer (score 2):

So many sentences would be rendered ungrammatical by implementing this suggestion that I don't think that it would be worthwhile. "Hey", for example, could appear at the beginning of a sentence as a valid topic of discussion.

Here are examples in which "so" appears as the first word of a post but deleting it would ruin the meaning:

- ["So shouldn't you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210536/so-shouldnt-you)
- [so called or so-called](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113069/so-called-or-so-called)

Here is an example in which "hey" appears as the first word of a post but deleting it would ruin the meaning:

- [Is addressing a guy as "guy" rude?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/187205/is-addressing-a-guy-as-guy-rude/187277#187277)

Comment: Re *'"Hey", for example, could appear at the beginning of a sentence as a valid topic of discussion'*: Can you [provide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/381091/edit) ***an example*** in your answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written right now)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum That sentence is the example.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan What about a real-world example, instead of just a hypothetical?  This question was posted 10+ years ago; [at the time when this specific site was still `meta.stackoverflow.com`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange); so with that in mind, do you have an example of a post on https://stackoverflow.com/ where the removal of "Hey," from a beginning of a post makes the rest of the sentence ungrammatical as you say?

Comment: @Daedalus No, I don't; I'm not a member of and have never participated in stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan ok, maybe you have examples from ELL or EL&U? Note that this question is about the first sentence of a post, not just any sentence in the middle.

Comment: @Marijn Done, with examples from both sites.

Comment: I understand where you’re coming from, but I don’t think a few cases where it would render a sentence ungrammatical ends up being very persuasive. The problem with removing individual words instead of full sentences is that there is no way for the simplistic system proposed to know whether it is changing the intent of the author or the perceived meaning of the post. The phrases are an annoyance and don’t merit butchering someone’s post with a regex or developing a ‘smart’ context-aware system that would be less likely to butcher it.

Comment: By making the issue about specific sentences, it causes the discussion to focus on how common those are and things that can be done to avoid those cases when we really should be talking about whether is is OK in principle to alter a post because the author’s style of writing annoys you.

Comment: @ColleenV My concern is not limited to grammar; when a sentence's grammar gets ruined, the author's meaning often becomes hard to understand, too. Therefore, my concern is largely about keeping an author's meaning clear, so I think we're in agreement on that.

Comment: I up-voted your post because we do agree... I was trying to explain why the tack you took in your argument might be getting a negative reaction. People are focusing on the wrong part of the argument. You don't get to auto-mangle someone's post because you find some turn of phrase annoying. Could you auto-mangle a post without making it ungrammatical or damaging the meaning too much? Yes, you can and if you claim you can't, some folks will find a solution for every case you throw at them while completely missing the point.